# How To Open an Existing project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, import

All the questions dealing with this are now outdated. I am simply trying to open an existing Android Studio project.
I have cloned a repository for a project from http://blog.stylingandroid.com/material-part-2/
I have all the files, I choose "Open an existing android studio project" and then choose the "Material" folder which is the root directory of the project. When the project loads, it is called "gradle" and there are no files showing in the project frame.
I am using the latest version of android studio and the latest build tools as of 19 Dec 2014.
How do I import a project?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From the Android Studio welcome screen, try "Import Non-Android Studio project". It sounds like exactly what wouldn't work, but it does.

Comment: This answer seems to be already accepted and also has +34 but to be honestly speaking, I do not see "Import Non-Android Studio project" in the Android Studio welcome screen. I am using Android Studio version 2.2.3. Can anyone please explain me?

Comment: I used import project which had eclipse and some other options in brackets, that seemed like the closest and it worked

Answer (score 14):

On 1.5.1, there's no `Import Non-Android Studio project` as the accepted answer says, but chosing `Import project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.)` does the trick. `Open an existing Android Studio project` does not work. Still quite weird.

Answer (score 0):

Click on file, then click on Open. select the main file that contains the project's name without opening the file.
then Gradle loads but still nothing happens and the welcome screen is shown. press the combined keys of Alt+1 then the project files will appear on the left side of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is tricky to open Android project. My tip is try to use

```
File -> Open... -> <path_to_settings.gradle>
```